# How to debug a node js file locally? Debugging a function that compares two arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a node js file(index.js) with a function to check if two arrays are equal and i want to debug why my funciton is not working. How can i debug it?

when i run the file by using (node index.js), it doesnt write to the console at all.

```js
function eql(arr1, arr2) {
  let isEqual = true;
  arr1.forEach((item, index) => {
    if(item !== arr2[index]) {
      console.log(item);
      console.log(arr2[index]);
      isEqual = false;
    }
  });
  return isEqual;
}
eql([], [1]);
```

Comment: https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I found that i am calling the function with an empty array and the forEach doesnt loop through at all. The debugging works if i pass an non empty array

Answer (score 0):

You can learn how to debug here: [node.js Debugging Guide](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).

However, your issue is that you are immediately assuming they are equal and then not going through any iterations to check actual equality.  `forEach` won't iterate an empty array.  Consider this solution instead which checks for length equality and then iterates all values using [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
function eql(arr1, arr2) {
  // Fail early if not same length
  if (arr1.length !== arr2.length) return false;

  // Make sure values are same between arrays
  return arr1.every((v, idx) => v === arr2[idx]);
}

console.log(eql([], [])); // true
console.log(eql([], [1])); // false
console.log(eql([1], [1])); // true
console.log(eql([1], [2])); // false
console.log(eql([1], [1, 2])); //false
```